# Get unique values from a MySql table column grouped with other column

Tags: mysql, self-join

This might be a very basic query practice for MySql experts, but I can't get a result as I'm expecting.

Below is the MySql query and the output pane. 
What I want to achieve is to get the bug_ids which is not present in the records for all cell_ids. In other words, looking at the records below we can see bug_ids 1,2,3,4 are present for all cell_ids 32,33,34. I want the records other than these bug_ids. So the expected output would be something like this,

```
project_id cell_id bug_id test_set_id case_id  
106        32      16     1           5  
106        33      16     1           5  
106        34       7     1           5
```

I have also tried using self join but couldn't found a proper query.

[image: Query with the output]

Please let me know if you need more info. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the list of bugs that are not in all the cells by doing:

```
select bug_id
from tran_cell_bug tcb
where cell_id in (32, 33, 34)
group by bug_id
having count(distinct cell_id) <> 3;
```

You can then use `join` to get the original values:

```
select tcb.*
from tran_cell_bug tcb join
     (select bug_id
      from tran_cell_bug tcb
      where cell_id in (32, 33, 34)
      group by bug_id
      having count(distinct cell_id) <> 3
     ) b
     on tcb.bug_id = b.bug_id;
```

Comment: I'll try this. I think it will be cell_id in place of bug_id in `where bug_id in (32, 33, 34)`? BTW thanks for quick rpl :)

Comment: Your first query runs great, but second query is not fetching the desired records. Could you explain in some detail how it works as I'm new to MySql.

Comment: @VPK . . . The second query just takes the result from the first query and joins back to the original table, to get the original values.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff for your help! One more thing, could you please explain the working of the statement `having count(distinct cell_id) <> 3;` for my understanding?

Comment: @FPK . . . That is counting the number of valid cells for each bug.  You have specified three cells in the `where` clause, so meeting your condition means that you don't have three cells for a bug.